# Using Angular ng-resource with multiple query parameters

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, web

I'm trying to send a request to the server with 4 parameters. It seems to work with less than 4, but I cannot get it to work with 4 or more. 
Here are the snippets:

```
        historyy: $resource('/history/:user.:item.:count.:cost', {

            user: '@userr',
            item: '@itemm',
            count: '@countt',
            cost: '@costt'
        }
```

Calling RestService:

```
   RestServices.historyy.get({userr: "Asd",itemm: $scope.item.id,countt: amount,costt: '0' });
```

When I execute this, the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/history/...?costt=0&countt=6&itemm=1&userr=Asd
```

Why is it adding these crazy (...?) ?. When I remove one of the parameter (no matter which one) it works properly.

Comment: Adding `?` to start of the query string is normal thing,  what the `.` next after the parameter does `$resource('/history/:user.:item.:count.:cost', {`, I think it should be `$resource('/history/:user:item:count:cost`

Comment: Are you using spring rest controller on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query` (see: [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource))

**Resource**

```
$resource('/history/');
```

**Call**

```
RestServices.historyy.query({user: "Asd", item: $scope.item.id, ...}, function(results) {
  //on success
});
```

**Result**

```
/history?user=Asd&item=ExampleItem...
```

**Spring REST Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/history", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SomeRestController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @JsonView(View.List.class)
    public List<SomeThing> getSomething(
        @RequestParam(value = "user", required = true) String user,
        @RequestParam(value = "item", required = true) String item, ...) {...}
```

You can find more information here: [Using $resource.query with params object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708081/angularjs-using-resource-query-with-params-object)